# azure synapse on demand, is external table cached?

Tags: azure-synapse

I am experimenting with the new Azure synapse on demand sql, I upload a small parquet file and created a new External table, my question is cache supported, if I run the same query, will it use the previous result or it will query the data again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not supported, you can vote for this feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics/suggestions/40486324-add-cache-for-on-demand-pool).